# Get selected value from Django ModelChoiceField form

Tags: django, django-forms

form

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    Country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.filter(Enabled=True), empty_label="Select Country", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  .
  .
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
     {{ addressForm.Country }}
  </div>
</form>
```

view

```
addressForm = AddressForm(request.POST, prefix="AddressForm")
country = addressForm['Country']
```

But the country variable contains the entire HTML element instead of the selected value. The same problems arise with any field in forms like `forms.CharField`

How can I retrieve the selected value from form elements?

Comment: Why are you accessing it at all? Is this post-validation?

Comment: I need to pass the data from the AddressForm to the model Address object to call the .save method (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to pass the data from the AddressForm to the model Address object to call the .save method (?)

Then you probably should be just using a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
     class Meta:
          model = Address
```

You can then just call `form.save()` and let django do the magic for you.

Either way, you should be calling `is_valid` prior to trying to access any data. This exposes the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary which contains all the forms values post-validation.

Comment: I knew about this but I faced some barriers: 1) Being able to apply my own css classes to the input elements 2) Being able to create a dropdown list for a model field of type .ForeignKey(Country....).

Comment: @John - If you have other questions then you should consider raising them as new questions with what you have tried and researched. If any of these answers solved this question, you should consider accepting it

Answer (score 4):

The way you get any field value: by calling `is_valid()` and then `form.cleaned_data[fieldname]`.

Comment: Can I use form.data[fieldname] instead of form.cleaned_data[fieldname].

Comment: No. That is the raw data from the post.

Comment: I am using form.data[fieldname] for getting record from modelchoicefield from form, Because form is sending me select(Dropdownlist) instead of value. Is it wrong or any security issue ?